# Batch seq2seq decoder

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, seq2seq

The following is from an seq2seq Tensorflow/Keras example the decodes 1 sequence… As noted, it says for simplicity they assume a batch size of 1. With the varying lengths of the sequences, would it even be possible to ‘batch’ predict the solutions? I don’t see a clear path to adjusting the code to handle the batch case.

Thanks in advance

```
def decode_sequence(input_seq):
    # Encode the input as state vectors.
    states_value = encoder_model.predict(input_seq)

    # Generate empty target sequence of length 1.
    target_seq = np.zeros((1, 1, num_decoder_tokens))
    # Populate the first character of target sequence with the start character.
    target_seq[0, 0, target_token_index["\t"]] = 1.0

    # Sampling loop for a batch of sequences
    # (to simplify, here we assume a batch of size 1).
    stop_condition = False
    decoded_sentence = ""
    while not stop_condition:
        output_tokens, h, c = decoder_model.predict([target_seq] + states_value)

        # Sample a token
        sampled_token_index = np.argmax(output_tokens[0, -1, :])
        sampled_char = reverse_target_char_index[sampled_token_index]
        decoded_sentence += sampled_char

        # Exit condition: either hit max length
        # or find stop character.
        if sampled_char == "\n" or len(decoded_sentence) > max_decoder_seq_length:
            stop_condition = True

        # Update the target sequence (of length 1).
        target_seq = np.zeros((1, 1, num_decoder_tokens))
        target_seq[0, 0, sampled_token_index] = 1.0

        # Update states
        states_value = [h, c]
    return decoded_sentence
```

Comment: you have to either add paddings or use ragged tensors

Comment: I have not used ragged tensors, so maybe there is something there I am unaware of, but as for the padding, the existing routine already does padded account for the different lengths of the sequences, so I must be missing something in your suggestion. The trouble I see is the 'exit' of the of the loop would not be the same for each item in the batch, as they all don't finish at the same time. Again, I could be missing something simple. Thanks

Comment: for the batch case you should stop predicting, when all sequences have ended (or you reached a number of maximum iterrations). However, maybe it is easier to use the Greedy Algorithm and Beam Search that are in Tensorflow Addons: https://www.tensorflow.org/addons/tutorials/networks_seq2seq_nmt